# Getting session variable in JSP page using Login Form Authentication provided by Jave EE

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, authentication

I'm following this guide [Securing web application](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/security.html) in order to create login form authentication in my web app. Unfortunately something don't satisfy me. I'm looking for a variable that I could use in a jsp page that say the user is logged on or not. for istance

```
<c:if test=${userIsLogged}>

</c:if
```

Does exist a way to get a variable linked to the session?

Comment: Server assigns the same cookie name (JSESSIONID) to all Web applications

Comment: I'm not understanding if it is a possible thing to do what I'd like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
<c:if test=${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}>

    User login:  ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}

</c:if
```

NOTE: This only works if you use Container login (JAAS).